# How to get RenderSliver position that wrapped inside RenderBox

Tags: flutter

I have a CustomScrollView widget that has SliverPersistentHeader, I want once it gets tapped the CustomScrollView offset to go to SliverPersistentHeader position, the problem is that SliverPersistentHeader is producing RenderSliver while CustomScrollView produces RenderBox, usually, if both were RenderBox I could just do RenderBox.localToGlobal(childOffset) but RenderSliver doesn't seem to have that attribute.

How to get that SliverPersistentHeader position?

Comment: what you mean by " the scroll offset to go to SliverPersistentHeader position"? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: The scroll offset that the CustomScrollView has, controlled via ScrollController. The SliverPersistentHeader is Tappable and once it tapped the ScrollController offset will jumpTo SliverPersistentHeader position.